# Why is response.body is a string instance when testing controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In the rspec test for my controller the response's body is always a string representation of an ActiveDispatch::Response instance.

```
=> #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x00000007863010
 ...
 @body=["#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x00000007530d70>"],...
```

The controller spec  in question:

```
it 'should not allow invalid email' do
     json = { :format => 'json', :patron_profile => { :email =>   'bogusemail.com', :password => 'password' } }
     post :create, json
     response.status.should eq(302)
     response.body.to_json.should be_json_eql(%({ 'error' : 'error message'}))
end
```

What could cause the `response.body` to be the ActionDispatch string shown above?

Comment: Did you try this with `render_views`?

Comment: Yes, but it had the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue [2074](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2074) on [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)'s Github account seems to be what is causing this issue.

As of Nov 4, 2012 a workaround is to use the git master branch of Devise in your Gemfile.